# Example for Separation axiom T0 T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6

Tags: general-topology

There are many type of topology Separation axiom T0 - T6, I search internet but I can only find the definition, Is there examples of each type of spaces (Like theis: T0 space but not T1, T1 space but not T2 .... T5 space but not T6)? Why they don't use only the strongest one?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom

T0  (Kolmogorov)

T1  (Fréchet)

T2  (Hausdorff)

T2½ (Urysohn)

completely T2   (completely Hausdorff)

T3  (regular Hausdorff)

T3½ (Tychonoff)

T4  (normal Hausdorff)

T5  (completely normal Hausdorff)

T6  (perfectly normal Hausdorff)

Comment: Obviously $\mathbb{R}$ could be the example of all separation axioms. Do you want examples which "separates" each of two separation axioms?

Comment: Yes, Like an example lists: T0 space but not T1, T1 space not T2 .... T5 space but not T6

Comment: See, each single one of these axioms has a dedicated Wikipedia page with **lots** of info on it (like, more than 280 characters). More often than not, there is a section titled "Examples and non-examples", or something to that effect. Chances are you won't be able to see it, though, until you've mastered the ancient art of scrolling down.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=t_0%20%2B%20%7E%20t_1) is meant for: on the spaces tab you can do queries (as the linked one) `t_0 + ~t_1` to find $T_0$ spaces that are not $T_1$, and you get links to descriptions of spaces like the excluded point topology, or the included point topology, etc.

Ditto up to `t_5 + ~t_6`; metric spaces obey all separation axioms up to and including $T_6$. All this can also be found via Wikipedia pages or old fashioned books like *Counterexamples in Topology*, on which $\pi$-base is largely based.